# Java - JFrame saving multiple lines

Tags: java, csv, jframe, save

I've been banging my head against the wall last couple of hours trying to get my program to work, but to no success.

I'm working on a simple JFrame based program that should open the window, let me input the variables and then if I press Save, save them to selected .csv file.

The problem however arises when I try to save 2 or more sets of variables, the first one always gets overwritten and only new one is there.

For example instead of:

Mark, 100, 2,
John, 50, 1

In the file I only find

John 50, 1

I'm guessing it has to do with new bufferedwriter being created every time I click 'Save' button but I have no idea how to get around doing that, I tried multiple positions of placing it but it never works because I get error if it's outside the Action method.

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Demonstrates etc
 */
public class Homework1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

   JTextField jtfName1;
   JTextField jtfName2;
   JTextField jtfName3;
   JTextField jtfName4;

   static File file = new File("121Lab1.csv"); 

   public Homework1() {
        // Set BorderLayout with horizontal gap 5 and vertical gap 10
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));


        // Create a JPanel with FlowLayout for the South of the JFrame's BorderLayout

      JPanel jpSouth = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 3));

        // Create some buttons to place in the south area
      JButton jbCalc = new JButton("Calculate");
      JButton jbSave = new JButton("Save");
      JButton jbClear = new JButton("Clear");
      JButton jbExit = new JButton("Exit");

      jpSouth.add(jbCalc);
      jpSouth.add(jbSave);
      jpSouth.add(jbClear);
      jpSouth.add(jbExit);

      jbCalc.addActionListener(this);
      jbSave.addActionListener(this);
      jbClear.addActionListener(this);
      jbExit.addActionListener(this);


        // Place the south panel in the JFrame's south area
      add(jpSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Add textfields to the rest of the frame

      JPanel jpCenter = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));

      jpCenter.add(new JLabel("Item name: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
      jtfName1 = new JTextField("", 10);
      jpCenter.add(jtfName1);
      jtfName1.addActionListener(this);

      jpCenter.add(new JLabel("Number of: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
      jtfName2 = new JTextField("", 10);
      jpCenter.add(jtfName2);
      jtfName2.addActionListener(this);

      jpCenter.add(new JLabel("Cost: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
      jtfName3 = new JTextField("", 10);
      jpCenter.add(jtfName3);
      jtfName3.addActionListener(this);

      jpCenter.add(new JLabel("Amount owed: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
      jtfName4 = new JTextField("", 10);
      jpCenter.add(jtfName4);
      jtfName4.addActionListener(this);

      add(jpCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      String actionString = ae.getActionCommand(); // gets the string on the component
      Object actionObj = ae.getSource();


      if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("Calculate")) { // ae.getSource() == jbCancel
         System.out.println("You clicked Calculate");
         try {
            double value = Double.parseDouble(jtfName2.getText())*Double.parseDouble(jtfName3.getText());
            jtfName4.setText(String.format("%.2f", value));
         } 
         catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            jtfName4.setText("Not a number");
         }

      } 
      else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("Save")) { 

         try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            writer.write(jtfName1.getText()+",");
            writer.write(jtfName2.getText()+",");
            writer.write(jtfName3.getText()+"\r\n");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
         } 
         catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Error");
         }         
      } 
      else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("Clear")) { 

         System.out.println("You clicked Clear");
         jtfName1.setText("");
         jtfName2.setText("");
         jtfName3.setText("");
         jtfName4.setText("");

      } 
      else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) { 


         setVisible(false);
         dispose();


      } 
      else {
         System.out.println("Unknown command: " + actionString);
         System.out.println("Unknown source:  " + actionObj);
      }
   } 




   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      Homework1 jfMain = new Homework1();
      jfMain.setTitle("Item Order Calculator");
      jfMain.setSize(450, 200);
      jfMain.setLocationRelativeTo(null);       // Center JFrame
      jfMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      jfMain.setVisible(true);


   } // end main
} // end class JPanelTester
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you click `save`, the file and it's contents are been overwritten.  You need to tell the `FileWriter` that you wish to append to the end of the file, for example...

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file), true);
```

See [`FileWriter(File, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)) for more details

`BufferedWriter` also has a `newLine` method, which can write a new line to the file...

```
writer.write(jtfName1.getText()+",");
writer.write(jtfName2.getText()+",");
writer.write(jtfName3.getText());
writer.newLine();
```

You're also not managing your resources very well.  If you open a resource, you should make every attempt to close it, otherwise you could end up with leaking resources and other strange problems

Luckily in Java 7+, it's very easy to manage these types of resources

```
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
        writer.write(jtfName1.getText()+",");
        writer.write(jtfName2.getText()+",");
        writer.write(jtfName3.getText());
        writer.newLine();
     } 
     catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error");
     }
```

See [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You could clear/delete the file on startup and append to the file like that: [How to append text to an existing file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you one other writer(i have worked on this):

```
try{ 

 PrintWriter Writer = new PrintWriter(new File("path of file/file.(whatever)");

    //example
        writer.write(jtfName1.getText()+",");
        writer.printf("  "); //Leave some space
        writer.write(jtfName2.getText()+",");
        writer.printf("  "); //Leave some space
        writer.write(jtfName3.getText()+"\r\n");
        writer.printf("  "); //Leave some space

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

if you want to leave some space or write something use:**writer.printf(".");**

if you want to leave a line use **writer.println();**

Of course it has and other fuctions to use with this writer..

Let me know if it does your job.....

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the using the `Writer` and, as far as your example goes, the `PrintWriter` doesn't really add any functionality that the OP doesn't already have (if you were formatting the `String`s in some way, that might be different). This will still only write the last content that the OP writes the file, overwriting the content...

Comment: for the save that the question need it does the job,i use it to save data into a program i am making..(it add the content one after other it can also append)  he/she can tranform it to do this.Ok i know BufferReader is one nice option but i haven't worked with this too much that's why i am suggestion this..

Comment: Same here, I tend to use the `Writer`s over `PrintWriter` personally, if you could say that it supported better character encoding or something, then that would be fine, but simply saying "you should use this because I do" isn't really a good reason for the OP to change - IMHO.

Comment: Also, you're example still isn't going to solve the issue of only the last element been written (the file been truncated), from the Java Docs *"`PrintWriter(File)` - The file to use as the destination of this writer. If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is buffered"*

Comment: hm the user want after saving to that file to append again .... ok here is a little problem with that writer yes..(i only used it to save one time and then close the file yes yes it overrides... thats true..)